# matplotlib plots strange horizontal lines on graph

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, pandas

I have used openpyxl to read data from an Excel spreadsheet into a pandas data frame, called 'tides'. The dataset contains over 32,000 rows of data (of tide times in the UK measured every 15 minutes). One of the columns contains date and time information (variable called 'datetime') and another contains the height of the tide (called 'tide'):

I want to plot datetime along the x-axis and tide on the y axis using:

```
import numpy        as np
import matplotlib       as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot    as plt
import pandas       as pd
import openpyxl
import datetime     as dt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

<-- Data imported from Excel spreadsheet into DataFrame using openpyxl. -->
<-- Code omitted for ease of reading.                                   -->

# Convert datatime variable to datetime64 format:
tides['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(tides['datetime'])

# Plot figure of 'datetime' vs 'tide':
fig = plt.figure()
ax_tides = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax_tides.plot_date(date2num(phj_tides['datetime']),phj_tides['tide'],'-',xdate=True,label='Tides 2011',linewidth=0.5)

min_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime('01/01/2011 00:00:00',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
max_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime('03/01/2011 23:59:45',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
ax_tides.set_xlim( [min_datetime, max_datetime] )

plt.show()
```

[image]

The plot shows just the first few days of data. However, at the change from one day to the next, something strange happens; after the last point of day 1, the line disappears off to the right and then returns to plot the first point of the second day - but the data is plotted incorrectly on the y axis. This happens throughout the dataset. A printout shows that the data seems to be OK.

```
    number            datetime   tide
0        1 2011-01-01 00:00:00  4.296
1        2 2011-01-01 00:15:00  4.024
2        3 2011-01-01 00:30:00  3.768
3        4 2011-01-01 00:45:00  3.521
4        5 2011-01-01 01:00:00  3.292
5        6 2011-01-01 01:15:00  3.081
6        7 2011-01-01 01:30:00  2.887
7        8 2011-01-01 01:45:00  2.718
8        9 2011-01-01 02:00:00  2.577
9       10 2011-01-01 02:15:00  2.470
10      11 2011-01-01 02:30:00  2.403
11      12 2011-01-01 02:45:00  2.389
12      13 2011-01-01 03:00:00  2.417
13      14 2011-01-01 03:15:00  2.492
14      15 2011-01-01 03:30:00  2.611
15      16 2011-01-01 03:45:00  2.785
16      17 2011-01-01 04:00:00  3.020
17      18 2011-01-01 04:15:00  3.314
18      19 2011-01-01 04:30:00  3.665
19      20 2011-01-01 04:45:00  4.059
20      21 2011-01-01 05:00:00  4.483

[21 rows x 3 columns]
     number            datetime   tide
90       91 2011-01-01 22:30:00  7.329
91       92 2011-01-01 22:45:00  7.014
92       93 2011-01-01 23:00:00  6.690
93       94 2011-01-01 23:15:00  6.352
94       95 2011-01-01 23:30:00  6.016
95       96 2011-01-01 23:45:00  5.690
96       97 2011-02-01 00:00:00  5.366
97       98 2011-02-01 00:15:00  5.043
98       99 2011-02-01 00:30:00  4.729
99      100 2011-02-01 00:45:00  4.426
100     101 2011-02-01 01:00:00  4.123
101     102 2011-02-01 01:15:00  3.832
102     103 2011-02-01 01:30:00  3.562
103     104 2011-02-01 01:45:00  3.303
104     105 2011-02-01 02:00:00  3.055
105     106 2011-02-01 02:15:00  2.827
106     107 2011-02-01 02:30:00  2.620
107     108 2011-02-01 02:45:00  2.434
108     109 2011-02-01 03:00:00  2.268
109     110 2011-02-01 03:15:00  2.141
110     111 2011-02-01 03:30:00  2.060

[21 rows x 3 columns]
       number            datetime   tide
35020   35021 2011-12-31 19:00:00  5.123
35021   35022 2011-12-31 19:15:00  4.838
35022   35023 2011-12-31 19:30:00  4.551
35023   35024 2011-12-31 19:45:00  4.279
35024   35025 2011-12-31 20:00:00  4.033
35025   35026 2011-12-31 20:15:00  3.803
35026   35027 2011-12-31 20:30:00  3.617
35027   35028 2011-12-31 20:45:00  3.438
35028   35029 2011-12-31 21:00:00  3.278
35029   35030 2011-12-31 21:15:00  3.141
35030   35031 2011-12-31 21:30:00  3.019
35031   35032 2011-12-31 21:45:00  2.942
35032   35033 2011-12-31 22:00:00  2.909
35033   35034 2011-12-31 22:15:00  2.918
35034   35035 2011-12-31 22:30:00  2.923
35035   35036 2011-12-31 22:45:00  2.985
35036   35037 2011-12-31 23:00:00  3.075
35037   35038 2011-12-31 23:15:00  3.242
35038   35039 2011-12-31 23:30:00  3.442
35039   35040 2011-12-31 23:45:00  3.671
```

I am at a loss to explain this. Can anyone explain what is happening, why it is happening and how can I correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Phil

Comment: Try converting your the pandas data series to lists or numpy array before plotting.

Comment: and look at the day changes in the list-form.

Comment: Can you post your data? I am unable to replicate the error with dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Finally found the answer. The original workflow was quite complicated. I stored the data in an Excel spreadsheet and used openpyxl to read data from a named cell range. This was then converted to a pandas DataFrame. The date-and-time variable was converted to datetime format using pandas' .to_datetime() function. And finally the data were plotted using matplotlib. As I was preparing the data to post to this forum (as suggested by rauparaha) and paring down the script to it bare essentials, I noticed that Day1 data were plotted on 01 Jan 2011 but Day2 data were plotted on 01 Feb 2011. If you look at the output in the original post, the dates are mixed formats: The last date given is '2011-12-31' (i.e. year-month-day') but the 2nd date representing 2nd Jan 2011 is '2011-02-01' (i.e. year-day-month).

So, looks like I misunderstood how the pandas .to_datetime() function interprets datetime information. I had purposely had not set the infer_datetime_format attribute (default=False) and had assumed any problems would have been flagged up. But it seems pandas assumes dates are in a month-first format. Unless they're not, in which case, it changes to a day-first format. I should have picked that up!

I have corrected the problem by providing a string that explicitly defines the datetime format. All is fine again.

Thanks again for your suggestions. And apologies for any confusion.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to replicate your error but perhaps my working dummy code can help diagnose the problem. I generated dummy data and plotted it with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ydata = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, num=200))
time_index = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), periods=200, freq=15*pd.datetools.Minute())
df = pd.DataFrame({'tides': ydata, 'datetime': time_index})
df.plot(x='datetime', y='tides')
```

My data looks like this

```
             datetime     tides
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00  0.000000
1 2000-01-01 00:15:00  0.050230
2 2000-01-01 00:30:00  0.100333
3 2000-01-01 00:45:00  0.150183
4 2000-01-01 01:00:00  0.199654

[200 rows]
```

and generates the following plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to try to replicate this problem. It's very much appreciated. I am currently out of the office and away from the computer with the data but I will try to post the data as soon as I return. Thanks again.